# iOS Cocos2d - FPS drops when moving many sprites

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I have a group of CCSprite objects that are all added to a batch node in a CCLayer. Those sprites should update their positions in the update method of the CCLayer.
The FPS is 60, and when the scene starts it is 60 but then it drops dramatically until it reaches 2 or 1 FPS!!
my update method (which runs 60 times per second) looks like this

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta {

    for (int i = 0; i<spritesArray.count; i++) {

        ((CCSprite *)[spritesArray objectAtIndex:i]).position = ccp(..., ...);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you surprised to see the fps go down using this?

Comment: How many sprites? What happens if you don't run the update code at all? PS: ignore the initial FPS, it takes a couple frames for FPS to settle in - it doesn't mean the layer is drawn at 60 fps initially, it only means the FPS counter took a moment to display the actual FPS. Actually it takes longer the slower the scene renders, and below 10 fps it becomes quite inaccurate anyway (not that it matters since any game drawing below 10 fps is unplayable).

Comment: Not all sprites are created on the same time. When the scene starts, a timer is started and each 1.0 time interval a new sprite is created. I  tried to create them all at once when the scene starts but no change in performance.
 The reason why I am updating the sprites positions in the layer's update method instead of just CCMove-ing them upon creation is that their movement paths are sine/cosine waves with varying amplitudes and wave lengths

Comment: Are these sprites batched? And how many are there and how big are they and on what device are you testing (disregard Simulator performance)?

Comment: Yes they are. There are about 30 sprites, each of around size 180*180. and testing on an iPad mini 1 (iOS 6.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make your live easier and iteration faster and code easier to read all at the same time, here's how to use fast enumeration to do the exact same thing:

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)delta 
{
    for (CCSprite* sprite in spritesArray)
    {
        sprite.position = ccp(..., ...);
    }
}
```

This is faster because it removes two message sends (count and objectAtIndex) for each iteration, plus internal optimizations due to using fast enumeration in the first place.

Comment: This has improved it a tiny bit.. the performance is still very sluggish